# API request through array

Tags: ruby, api, youtube

I am using Youtube API, and especially the video item. 
This is my code :

```
# Sample ruby code for videos.list, in order to get tags and categoryId for a specific video

def videos_list_multiple_ids(service, part, **params)
  params = params.delete_if { |p, v| v == ''}
  response = service.list_videos(part, params)
  print_results(response)
end




videos_list_multiple_ids(service, 'snippet',
  id: 'DTTwp6J47Sw, xSY75qJ_kIk')
```

Instead of `id: 'DTTwp6J47Sw, xSY75qJ_kIk')` , i have an array with multiples id's.

How can I make the request through my array ?

Thank you

Comment: `id: your_array.join(', ')` where `your_array` is something like `['DTTwp6J47Sw', 'xSY75qJ_kIk']`

Comment: it works perfectly than you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-join) to turn an array into a comma separated string:

```
ids = ['DTTwp6J47Sw', 'xSY75qJ_kIk']
ids.join(', ')
#=> "DTTwp6J47Sw, xSY75qJ_kIk"
```

Applied to your code:

```
videos_list_multiple_ids(service, 'snippet', id: ids.join(', '))
```